# Resampling Multiple tiff files in R

Tags: r, raster, resampling, r-raster

I need your small help in resampling multiple files with the same name but in different folders using R.

I have a folder with image name ranging from 1:172 in reclass1.
I have another folder with image name ranging from 1:172 in reclass2.
I need to resample 1.tif in reclass 1 with 1.tif in reclass2 and similarly to all 172 files. I can do single resampling but unable to do all in a loop.

I tried:

```
setwd("D:/archived_121316_before_files/Reclass2") 
rlist2 = list.files(getwd(), pattern="tif$", full.names=FALSE) 
for(i in rlist2) {
  assign(unlist(strsplit(i, "[.]"))[1], raster(i)) 
} 
setwd("D:/archived_121316_before_files/Reclass1") 
rlist1=list.files(getwd(), pattern="tif$", full.names=FALSE) 
for(j in rlist1) {
  assign(unlist(strsplit(j, "[.]"))[1], raster(j)) 
}
resample(i, j, method="ngb")
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I treid this but i am very new in R so it might look ridiculous.

Comment: setwd("D:/archived_121316_before_files/Reclass2")

rlist2=list.files(getwd(), pattern="tif$", full.names=FALSE)

for(i in rlist2) { assign(unlist(strsplit(i, "[.]"))[1], raster(i)) } 

setwd("D:/archived_121316_before_files/Reclass1")

rlist1=list.files(getwd(), pattern="tif$", full.names=FALSE)

for(j in rlist1) { assign(unlist(strsplit(j, "[.]"))[1], raster(j)) } ,                                                          

resample(i, j,method="ngb")

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```
# list all files in reclass1 folder
  flname1 <- list.files(path = 'D:/reclass1/', pattern = '.tif')
  nfile1 <- length(flname1)

# list all files in reclass2 folder
  flname2 <- list.files(path = 'D:/reclass2/', pattern = '.tif')
  nfile2 <- length(flname2)

# Resample reclass1 image based on reclass2 image
  for (i in 1:nfile1) {
    r1<-raster(flname1[[i]])    
    r2<-raster(flname2[[i]])    
    rs<-resample(r1,r2,method='bilinear') # you can  choose your own method

    # Save the ouput
    write.Raster(rs, paste0('D:/resample/rs_',i,'.img'), overwrite=T)
  }
```

Comment: Very straightforward answer, but it should be noted that for a substantial number of rasters, or even a few large raster, this solution could take an awful long time. It does however seem like an easily parallelized problem.

Comment: Please add an explanation to go along with your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very kind help